# Búsqueda en Php y MySQLi imprimir detalles

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy entrando al mundo de `PHP` y estoy tratando de implementar una búsqueda, tengo una lista de empleados un formulario de búsqueda y cuando escriban el nombre debe salir la información detallada del usuario, entonces en la la parte búsqueda lo implemente pero me sale error

> mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\wamp64\www\employees_done\views\emp_search.php

En esto es mi código de búsqueda

```
<form method="get" action="index.php" name="searchform" id="searchform">
<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="search">
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    

  $search=$_POST['emp_list'];

  $query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM employees_assign WHERE emp_fname LIKE '%{$search}%' || emp_lname LIKE '%{$search}%' ");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
  while ($emp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$emp['emp_fname']."</td><td></td><td>".$emp['emp_lname']."</td></tr>";
  }
}else{
    echo "No employee Found<br><br>";
  }

}else{                          
  $query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'employees_assign'");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$emp['emp_fname']."</td><td></td><td>".$emp['emp_lname']."</td></tr>";
  }
}

mysqli_close();
?>
```

Voy por buen camino, ¿Por qué espera más parámetros? , ¿Como  imprimo los detalles?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` debería recibir dos parámetros para su caso. la `conexión` y la `query` a ejecutar. `mysqli_query($conexion,'selec....')` por otra parte su código es muy inseguro y se presta para posibles ataques , para más detalles debería leer [¿Cómo puedo evitar que la inyección SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) _(El más común.)_

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) Espera dos parámetros para su caso *(estilo procedimientos)*. La `conexión` *(Qué no es visible en el código de ejemplo , pero asumo que hace la conexión con la BD)*  es decir el valor de retorno de [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php)  y la `query` a ejecutar.

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("host", "usuario", "password", "bd");
mysqli_query($conexion,'selec....');
```

> Por otra parte su código es muy inseguro y se presta para posibles
>   ataques , para más detalles debería leer [¿Cómo puedo evitar que la
>   inyección
>   SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)
>   *(El más común.)*